# EF 6 Core exec proc stock with count returning int

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF 6 with .NET Core and I want to execute a stored procedure that makes a join between 5 tables and returns the count of line:

```
Select Count(*) 
from MyFamily m
inner join Customer c on m.CustomerId = c.id
.....
```

In the service I call my repository

```
 _familyRepository.GetCountFromSql("EXEC sp_CountFamilyScreenShot);
```

In my code I'm using this generic method:

```
public Task<int> GetCountFromSql(string sql, params object[] parameters)
{
    return _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(sql, parameters);
}
```

But I think `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync` is not the right method to use because it always returns -1

Do you know how I can execute my stored procedure and get the int of the count?

Comment: If you're using EF, you don't need stored procedures. There's no advantage to using them (there was long ago, but not anymore). Please give the compete sql query, so we can give you the equivalent Linq code.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Could you show us how you call `GetCountFromSql`? Give a [mcve]. I bet there's no `await`. Why are you using the async method?

Answer (score 0):

Here i give you link how you can get datatable from dbcontext. With that you need just return count of the sql from your stored procedure. Than you can take it to datable and you are able to return value with Convert.ToInt32(datatable.Rows[0][0])

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5263745/Return-DataTable-Using-Entity-Framework

Comment: No i dont want to main that. Your procedure is fine and just return resultset with count(*). You can get this count with datatable and you can return just integer value of that.

Comment: @JHBonarius - I think you have misunderstood. If the query being used selects `COUNT(*)`, then the entire table is *not* loaded to memory. .Fill is just loading the returned count to the first cell of the first row of the datatable..

Please think before being rude to someone who actually posted a good solution that doesn't even have the issue you claim it does.

Comment: @johnglenn thanks for pointing that out. I indeed misread. I apologize for that. Still, when using EF, I would not advice to use a `DataTable`. It's still not the right tool for the job. EF either has `context.Database.SqlQuery` or indeed `ExecuteSqlCommand`