# Convert SQL stored procedure to Linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, entity-framework-core

I created the following stored procedure:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[LeadScoring_CountClosedActions]
    (@UserId INT,
     @StartDate INT,
     @EndDate INT)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT TOP 1 
        COUNT(l.Extra) OVER () AS TotalRecords
    FROM 
        [dbo].[LeadScoringActions] AS a
    INNER JOIN 
        [dbo].[LeadScoringLeads] AS l ON a.LeadId = l.LeadId
    WHERE 
        a.AssignedToUserId = @UserId 
        AND a.DateCompleted > DATEADD(DAY, @StartDate, GETDATE())
        AND a.DateCompleted <= DATEADD(DAY, @EndDate, GETDATE())
        AND a.ActionResultType != 'System Closed'
        AND l.Extra IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY 
        l.Extra
END
```

And I was trying to execute it with the following in EF Core:

```
var count = await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync($"exec LeadScoring_CountClosedActions @UserId={userId}, @StartDate={request.StartDate}, @EndDate={request.EndDate}");
```

But it was always returning -1 so I had a look around and it would seem I should convert the stored procedure to Linq (see one of the comments on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70822830/ef-6-core-exec-proc-stock-with-count-returning-int))

I was wondering how I would do that - I know how to do the general bits:

```
var count = await _context
                    .Actions
                    .Include(a => a.Lead)
                    .CountAsync(a => a.ActionResultType != LeadScoringConstants.SystemClosed &&
                                     a.DateCompleted > DateTime.Today.AddDays(request.StartDate) &&
                                     a.DateCompleted <= DateTime.Today.AddDays(request.EndDate) &&
                                     a.AssignedToUserId == userId &&
                                     a.Lead.Extra != null);
```

But I'm not sure how to do the `GROUP BY` - in the linq, it would be grouped by `a.Lead.Extra` or if it's possible to do a `COUNT OVER`?

Is it better to do it as linq or is there a way to execute the stored procedure and get the correct result?

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#basic-sql-queries

Comment: Window functions are not supported by EF Core.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I solved it using linq by getting the matching actions from the db then I got the distinct extra properties from the results and counted them:

```
var actions = await _context
                .Actions
                    .Include(a => a.Lead)
                .Where(a =>
                    a.ActionResultType != LeadScoringConstants.SystemClosed &&
                    a.DateCompleted > DateTime.Today.AddDays(request.StartDate) &&
                    a.DateCompleted <= DateTime.Today.AddDays(request.EndDate) &&
                    a.AssignedToUserId == userId &&
                    a.Lead.Extra != null)
                .ToListAsync();

var projectIds = actions.Select(a => a.Lead.Extra).Distinct().Count();
```

As per comments, I can change this to be done in linq:

```
var count = await _context
    .Actions
    .Where(a =>
        a.ActionResultType != LeadScoringConstants.SystemClosed &&
        a.DateCompleted > DateTime.Today.AddDays(request.StartDate) &&
        a.DateCompleted <= DateTime.Today.AddDays(request.EndDate) &&
        a.AssignedToUserId == userId &&
        a.Lead.Extra != null)
    .Select(a => new { a.Lead.Extra, a.DateCompleted })
    .Distinct()
    .CountAsync();
```

Comment: It is terrible. Remove `.ToListAsync()` and `Include` also obviously. Loading records to calculate count - it is far away from perfection.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv instead of saying everything I can't do or everything I've done is terrible, why not be a little more helpful and show me how to do it properly then?

Comment: At first sight I do not understand this SQL, grouping with Count OVER... Just correct your answer, remove `Include` and `await .. ToListAsync` and you will have right generated SQL.

Comment: Include Is not for this LINQ query. You need just `Count`. Include ONLY for loading related entities. ToListAsync is not needed, leave first part as `IQueryable`.